# C++ : read a csv file and extract some parts

Tags: c++, csv, extract

A `.csv` file is written like this:

```
    M9005U00-X30A0S00-1;BAS;X;-0.002;-0.095
    S707RY00-X30AOS00-1;HMV;X;+0.002;+0.081
    W3005U00-X30BOJ00-1;BAS;X;+0.026;-0.138
    H307QZ00-X30BOJ00-1;HMV;X;-0.025;+0.122
    ....
```

now I want to create a function, i.e.

```
      double find_and_extract (string sss)
```

when this function is used with a keyword as its parameter, for example

```
      find_and_extract (W3005U00-X30BOJ00-1);
```

it will search in the .csv file line by line, find corresponding line (in this case it should be the third line), and extract the certin part "+0.026" in this line, return as a double.

How should I write this function?

edit: Here is the code i've written so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    void main()
        {
           find_and_extract (W3005U00-X30BOJ00-1);
        }

    double find_and_extract (string sss)
         {
             vector<string> vecarray;
             ifstream infile("C:\\Data\\testdata.csv");
             string temppo;
             string contnt;
             char csv_extract[40];
             stringstream ss;
             vector <string>::iterator ptr;
             while (!infile.eof())
               { 
                 infile.getline(csv_extract,40);
                 ss << csv_extract;
                 ss >> contnt;
                 vecarray.push_back(contnt);
                }
             for (ptr=vecarray.begin();ptr!=vecarray.end();ptr++)
             {
                 if ((*ptr).find(sss)==0)
                     temppo = (*ptr).substr(27,6);
             }
             return (strtod(temppo.c_str(),NULL,0));
        }
```

Could anyone help me out to point out the errors?

Comment: -1: do you expect someone to do your work instead of you? The answer is probably - you should write this function using well-known best-practices, keeping maintainablity in mind and handling possible errors.

Comment: I'd say a combination of `getline`, `substr` and `strtod` would be an option.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, even if it doesn't work? If you're stuck at the beginning, please indicate that, and why you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you already have the file as a string, I'd use the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm to find the key, find the position of the 3rd and 4th semi-colons on that line and return the string in between them.

That's just an outline - you'll need to add error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed: This way, you could search for the key very efficiently, without having to implement an algorithm yourself. When you found the key, you can let sed output the parts of the line you need (use regular expressions to describe the pattern and groupings to print only part of it). After that, it's a simple string to float conversion that can be done in a programming language of your choice.

For starters:

```
sed -n 's/RegexToMatchYourKeyAndValues/MatchedValues/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `strtok()`. This is actually a pretty trivial task, and should be a good learning project if you are still new to C++.

Comment: `std::string::substr` and `std::string::find` are better since `strtok` actually modifies the string.

Comment: I didn't see anything about not modifying the string in the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If the text lines in the file are the same length, you may want to read the lines as blocks (i.e. many lines == 1 block) into a buffer, then search the buffer.

Your performance bottleneck will the reading the data from the file.  In general, the search method you choose will be faster than reading in the data.